# Workaround for css animations if windows user not enabling animations

Tags: css-animations, windows-10-universal

I just noticed that no animations from example animated.css is working if the user is using win 10. This is because of that animations is disabled by default in win 10. So I dont think it has anything to do with browser support.

I think this is a problem because the average user dont know about this setting and all animations is lost for them.

Everything works fine on mac and chrome/safari and on iphone. Also tried and huawei tablet and it worked there to.

I also read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Anyone has a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Some people disable animations because it causes them migrates or epileptic fits. You want to override that choice and impose those health issues on them?

Comment: No of course not! But its still annoying that the rest of the people is missing the experience I'm creating on websites. I mean could'nt be the other way around that it is enabled by default and have the choice to disable it?